# Dynamic where clause in share component oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

How i can create dynamic share component with dynamic where clause in oracle apex and assign the value to where clause in share component
Note the assigned value not from item i want to assign value manual how i can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either

1. base your query on a [pipelined function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions).
2. Use the "Function Returning SQL" source type when creating an LOV
3. Use the [web source](https://www.maxapex.com/blogs/expanded-shared-lovs/) option, which would have it's own logic